# Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'

Tags: flutter

I have a problem with my code. Everything worked before but now im getting this error. I think it is a very little mistake, but I cant see it? I'm very new in flutter and have not so much knowledge. From now on i am doing a video course. Can anybody help me?

Thank you!

Error-Message:

```
#0      Products.fetchAndSetProducts.<anonymous closure> (package:shop_app_flutter/providers/products.dart:83:26)
#1      __InternalLinkedHashMap&_HashVMBase&MapMixin&_LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:367:8)
#2      Products.fetchAndSetProducts (package:shop_app_flutter/providers/products.dart:80:21)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      _ProductsOverviewScreenState.didChangeDependencies (package:shop_app_flutter/screens/products_overview_screen.dart:41:38)
#4      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3862:12)
#5      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3717:5)
#6      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2961:14)
#7      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2764:12)
#8      SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/f<…>
```

products.dart:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

import '../models/http_exception.dart';
import './product.dart';

class Products with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Product> _items = [];


  List<Product> get items {
    return [..._items];
  }

  List<Product> get favoriteItems {
    return _items.where((prodItem) => prodItem.isFavorite).toList();
  }

  Product findById(String id) {
    return _items.firstWhere((prod) => prod.id == id);
  }



  Future<void> fetchAndSetProducts() async {
    const url = 'https://flutter-update.firebaseio.com/products.json';
    try {
      final response = await http.get(url);
      final extractedData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
      if (extractedData == null) {
        return;
      }
      final List<Product> loadedProducts = [];
      extractedData.forEach((prodId, prodData) {
        loadedProducts.add(Product(
          id: prodId,
          title: prodData['title'],
          description: prodData['description'],
          price: prodData['price'],
          isFavorite: prodData['isFavorite'],
          imageUrl: prodData['imageUrl'],
        ));
      });
      _items = loadedProducts;
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (error) {
      throw (error);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you show us the Product class and an example of the JSON response? Looks like you have a parsing issue.

Comment: Agree with @Miguel. 'String id'/prodId is the prime suspect. Please check if the 'id' in json is string or integer.

Comment: ```class Product with ChangeNotifier {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final String description;
  final double price;
  final String imageUrl;
  bool isFavorite;

  Product({
    @required this.id,
    @required this.title,
    @required this.description,
    @required this.price,
    @required this.imageUrl,
    this.isFavorite = false,
  });```

Comment: this doesn't work...

Comment: also, are you sure your url is correct? when I query this endpoint I get ```{
  "error" : "Firebase error. Please ensure that you spelled the name of your Firebase correctly"
}```

Comment: Now i've changed to this url: https://flutter-shop-app-8cf59.firebaseio.com/products.json.

And when i do the .json away this error comes:
Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at line 2, character 1)

Comment: I now see a permission denied error when querying your endpoint. I'd suggest you to paste the correct json in the question and we can help you debug it. If not, I think the issue is that the url you provided doesn't work.